# What is the folder called base in the structure of the project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I've updated the android studio, when I create a new project I noticed a folder called base and it cause me problems in gradle.

[image]

How can I remove it safely?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the folder called base in the structure of the project?

Given your screenshot, you seem to have set up your project with *Instant App* support. With instant apps, you split your project into multiple "feature" modules that the end user can "instantly" load up. All of these modules share "base" code, which is where all the shared / base / common logic lives.

> Recently I've updated the android studio, when I create a new project I noticed a folder called base and it cause me problems in gradle.

What does "it cause me problems in gradle" mean?

> How can I remove it safely?

Do you actually want instant apps support? If not, I'd say start over and create a brand new project that explicitly does not have instant apps support.

Comment: problems like a compilation error
And I created a new project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying / asking.